# HttpsRedirect on ASP.NET Core app causing infiinite loop

Tags: asp.net-core, https

I have an ASP.NET Core app running on Heroku. I want to force redirect to https so I can setup a PWA, I have added the following to my startup.cs file, but when I deploy to Heroku I get an error

> The page redirected you too many times

in the network tab, the first request is to http and then all the rest are to https, but all have the `307 temporary redirect`.

This is the code in my `startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => 
        {
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });

    // more settings
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    // ....
}
```

Is there something I am missing to ensure my app forces https?

Comment: Have a look at [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu)